# Is there a brothel for women in Game Of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Well we know that there are brothels in every town in the Game Of Thrones and it is it always shown that the men frequent them.

But, is there any back story to the Brothels in the Seven Kingdoms?

We do see Ellaria Sand visit the brothel with Oberyn Martell, but that is the extent of a woman visiting a brothel as a paying customer.

Any such information the books on this topic?

Comment: Catelyn Stark hid in a brothel owned by Petyr Bailish in episode 3 of season 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Snow But that is not the scenario you are asking about.

Comment: It's worth noting that even in our own historical record, there is scant evidence of women visiting brothels let alone a brothel FOR women. Westeros shares European society's historic condemnation of homosexuality, so I'm not sure why it would be any different.

Comment: @TenthJustice: I believe OP is asking about a brothel full of male employees and female guests, not homosexuality.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We do not see any dedicated "female brothel" (a brothel that would be frequented by women and staffed by male whores).

However, we do see in that same encounter when Oberyn vists the brothel that "everything in Littlefinger's establishment has a price".

Littlefinger himself also implies that he will serve any fetish as long as the gold is right. Varys even suggests he has even provided fresh cadavers for a high paying customer. [This scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV6ecIfYBg4) from *The Wolf and the Lion (S1E5)*

> [Petyr] You look a bit lonely today. You should pay a visit to my brothel this evening. **First boy** is on the house.
>
> [Varys] I think you are mistaking business with pleasure.
>
> [Petyr] Am I? All those little birds that whisper in your ear, such pretty little things. Trust me, **we accommodate all inclinations.**
>
> [Varys] Oh, I'm sure. **Lord Redwyne like his boys very young**, I hear.
>
> [Petyr] I'm a purveyor of beauty and **discretion**, both equally important.
>
> [Varys] But, though I suppose beauty is a subjective quality, no? Is true that **Ser Marlon of Tumblestone prefers amputees?**
>
> [Petyr] **All desires are valid to a man with a full purse.**
>
> [Varys] And I heard the most awful rumor of **a certain lord with taste for fresh cadavers,** must be enormously difficult to accommodate that inclination. The logistics alone, to find beautiful corpses before they rot.
>
> [Petyr] Strictly speaking, such a thing would not be in accordance with the King's Laws.
>
> [Varys] Strictly speaking!

Another example would be the young girls Meryn Trant requests while in Braavos.

So while it may not be a common occurrence, find the right smut peddler and have enough gold, you can have whatever you like! I am sure there are women with enough gold and desire to seek Littlefinger's discretion...

Comment: @KyloRen You've been asking good questions! Granted, I think any GoT question is a good question :P

Comment: Have been watching GOT from the beginning to the last season all over again. I tend to really get into these kind of shows, but I don't have time to read the books.

Comment: Ignoring any crazy fetishes, aren't there just some scantily clad guys running around Little Finger's establishment?